# Using Active Directory data in Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, active-directory, membership-provider

I have services (WCF) who do research in Active Directory to provide data to various applications using Microsoft Membership Provider, and also need some of this information in some queries in a SQL Server 2008 database, I generated a dll and registered in my Sql server, but I have a performance problem of my services, with the number of users increasing services stop frequently, after some reports noted that the memory usage increases exponentially. I wonder what the best practice to communicate with Active Directory, register a .dll in Sql Server or use OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services?

Basically I have a layer with WCF services which have several methods, GetUserById, GetUserByName, UsersInRole, GetRolesByUser, GetUserGroups, GetUsersInGroup, etc.

In my database I have a DLL that references this service, and use these methods as a database function to get the information I need and so filter my data.

This is a sitema BI, have different levels of access to information, and all security is based on Active Directory and must be managed by the security team information. The purpose of my question is whether it is a good practice to use this DLL with the functions in SQL Server, or if I should do the LDAP searches directly in my queries within the database.

Comment: Having SQL Server run code that's not database-related is icky (in my opinion, your mileage may vary). Have you already considered and discarded the option of using a separate service to query this data and store it in tables, which queries can get at more easily?

Comment: My biggest problem is that the security part can not be stored directly in my database, this part is managed by a separate security team based on Active Directory groups, so in my database I just keep what groups have access to which roles, every query have to consult the User requesting the information is part of a group that has access to specific information. In the same screen, the user can have option to view information from a client and the other not.

Comment: If all you need is checking group membership, you can use integrated authentication and [IS_MEMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186271), but it depends on your scenario whether this is appropriate. Maybe you could update your question with more details on how the responsibilities are separated between the front-end(s) and the database?